# split list properly from subprocess output

Tags: python, list, csv, split, export-to-csv

I ran subprocess.run on a separate .py file which gives me a messy list that is difficult to read. I have made a for loop that produces a csv file for each iteration and one of the iterations look like:

```
Version 3.1.5.0\r\nGetFileName C:\\users\\trinh\\downloads\\higgi022_test.raw\r\nGetCreatorID thermo\r\nGetVersionNumber 64\r\nGetCreationDate time.struct_time(tm_year=1970, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=11, tm_min=51, tm_sec=11, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=0)\r\nIsNewFile False\r\nIsThereMSData True\r\nHasExpMethod True\r\nInAcquisition False\r\nGetNumberOfControllers 1\r\nGetAcquisitionDate \r\nGetUniqueCompoundNames ('',)\r\nGetInstrumentDescription \r\nGetInstrumentID 0\r\nGetInstSerialNumber SN03464B\r\nGetInstName **LTQ Orbitrap Velos**\r\nGetInstModel LTQ Orbitrap Velos\r\nGetInstSoftwareVersion 2.6.0 SP3\r\nGetInstHardwareVersion \r\nGetNumInstMethods 4\r\nGetInstMethodNames ('LTQ', 'EksigentNanoLcCom_DLL', 'NanoLC-AS1 Autosampler', 'EksigentNanoLc_Channel2')\r\nGetVialNumber 0\r\nGetInjectionVolume 0.0\r\nGetInjectionAmountUnits \r\nGetSampleVolume 0.0\r\n############################################## END SECTION###################################\r\n
```

I tried using the split() method to get it into a more manageable list, however it introduces white space for some of the results, like the result for 'LTQ Orbitrap Velos', it is outputted as 3 lines.

I want the results to be on one line, similar to the cmd prompt. Using .split('\n') doesn't achieve what I want either because it makes the item and result as one row. Ideally, I want a header that is on the top row (or left-most column) and the iterated lists underneath (or to the right of the first column).

[image: cmd prompt output]

I wanted to make a dictionary but the items and results would not match up since the two lists would not have the same number of elements and so the use of zip() function would not help. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're ok with just showing the header, then the result on the next line.  The following should do that with your example.

```
def cleanup(rslts):
    # looking at the following line, working from inside outward:
    # first split rslts on new lines
    # then loop over it (`for r in rslts.split...`)
    # but only accept lines which are not empty (the `if r` clause)
    # now, we just loop over each line from that generator 
    # expression - the `for aline in (...)` part
    for aline in (r for r in rslts.split('\r\n') if r):
        # treat the `END SECTION` differently - just print it
        if aline.startswith('###'):
            print(aline)
            continue  # goes back to the `for line in (...)`

        # `aline.split(' ', 1) splits on spaces, but a maximum of 1 time
        # now assign `header` the first thing on the left of the `=`
        # and `footer` the next item
        header, remainder = aline.split(' ', 1)  
        print(header)
        print(remainder)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # messy results below:
    rslts = """Version 3.1.5.0\r\nGetFileName C:\\users\\trinh\\downloads\\higgi022_test.raw\r\nGetCreatorID thermo\r\nGetVersionNumber 64\r\nGetCreationDate time.struct_time(tm_year=1970, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=11, tm_min=51, tm_sec=11, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=0)\r\nIsNewFile False\r\nIsThereMSData True\r\nHasExpMethod True\r\nInAcquisition False\r\nGetNumberOfControllers 1\r\nGetAcquisitionDate \r\nGetUniqueCompoundNames ('',)\r\nGetInstrumentDescription \r\nGetInstrumentID 0\r\nGetInstSerialNumber SN03464B\r\nGetInstName **LTQ Orbitrap Velos**\r\nGetInstModel LTQ Orbitrap Velos\r\nGetInstSoftwareVersion 2.6.0 SP3\r\nGetInstHardwareVersion \r\nGetNumInstMethods 4\r\nGetInstMethodNames ('LTQ', 'EksigentNanoLcCom_DLL', 'NanoLC-AS1 Autosampler', 'EksigentNanoLc_Channel2')\r\nGetVialNumber 0\r\nGetInjectionVolume 0.0\r\nGetInjectionAmountUnits \r\nGetSampleVolume 0.0\r\n############################################## END SECTION###################################\r\n"""
    cleanup(rslts)  # pass messy results into a function to pretty up output
```

Comment: Hi Gerrat, thanks for your quick reply. I am quite new to Python and I'm having difficulty following your code. Can you please break it down in layman's terms what you did? Thanks.

Comment: @SpencerTrinh:  I added a number of comments.  Let me know if you'd like more clarification on anything.